# How to make a PDF/Document library

Tags: plugins

I want to setup an online library where you can search, read and download PDFs (and other formats like epub) which will include ebooks and various documents like scientific articles. Kind of like a small version of Scribd or b-ok.cc.

I know how to do this from scratch but I would much prefer to use plugins and code that already exists rather than reinvent the wheel.

Also it would be really nice if I could import my calibre library into it rather than populate the database from scratch. Even better would be to sync it with the e-caliber library.

Which plugins would be best to use for this?

The plugin that looks the best is the BARN2 WordPress Table Posts Pro plugin but it's expensive, too much to pay for non commercial use.

Another plugin I found is this: https://github.com/fleshgordo/calibrewordpress

I'll try it but it looks pretty limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Relevanssi](https://www.relevanssi.com/) plugin which allows you to [search PDF files](https://www.relevanssi.com/knowledge-base/indexing-searching-pdfs-wordpress/). Upload the PDFs to the media library. This will make them attachment "posts." Relevanssi can now index them. Make sure that Relevanssi will display PDFs in the search results.

As for importing your Calibre library, you might be able to use [the plugin you mentioned](https://github.com/fleshgordo/calibrewordpress) to create a blog post (or a [custom post type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)) with the PDF files attached/included somehow. Otherwise, if it's possible to export all of your e-books from Calibre as PDFs, you could do that and upload them all to the WordPress media library. If you want to be able to write a description for them, you'll want to make sure that whatever theme you use can display file descriptions.

**Edit:** Here are two plugins that I found just by searching "document library" in the WordPress plugin repository. They both appear to be free, but they might not be what you're looking for:

- [Memphis Documents Library](https://wordpress.org/plugins/memphis-documents-library/)
- [WP Documents Library](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-documents-library/)

Also, if you're planning on using WordPress only as a document library, you might want to consider using software designed for document managment. Here are two free ones I found:

- [OpenDocMan](https://www.opendocman.com/)
- [SeedDMS](https://www.seeddms.org/)

You'll have to host them yourself. Depending on what hosting provider and plan you have, you might be able to use the same hosting.